# Cross references between slides and its content

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown, beamer

In an R markdown presentation with output format `beamer` (to generate a LaTex/PDF file), is it possible to create cross-references between slides, i.e. pages of the final PDF?
This would be very helpful to quickly jump between slides, e.g. to navigate to an appendix at the end of the presentation.

I tried to use bookdown commands as proposed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54041552/impossible-to-cross-referring-figures-and-tables-with-beamer-presentation-opti), but without success.

### MWE:

````
---
title: "Cross references between slides"
output:
  # beamer_presentation: default
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rmarkdown::beamer_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Bullets with references

- Bullet 1: \ref{tab:my-table}
- Bullet 2: \ref{fig:my-plot}
- Bullet 3: \ref{appendix}

## Bullets with references (bookdown)

- Bullet 1: \@ref(tab:my-table)
- Bullet 2: \@ref(fig:my-plot)
- Bullet 3: \@ref(appendix)

## table

```{r my-table, cars, echo = TRUE}
library(kableExtra)
kable(summary(cars))
```

## plot

```{r my-plot, pressure}
plot(pressure)
```

## appendix

my appendix
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For linking to the appendix, you can use

```
- Bullet 3: \hyperlinkappendixstart{appendix}
```

If you examine the tex code produced by your MWE you will see that your table and figure are both included without caption or `figure`/`table` environment, but you can reference the slide they are on

```
- Bullet 1: \hyperlink{table}{table}
- Bullet 2: \hyperlink{plot}{plot}
```

MWE:

````
---
title: "Cross references between slides"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "default"
    keep_tex: true
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex    

---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Bullets with references

- Bullet 1: \hyperlink{table}{table}
- Bullet 2: \hyperlink{plot}{plot}
- Bullet 3: \hyperlinkappendixstart{appendix}


## table


```{r my-table, cars, echo = TRUE}
library(kableExtra)
kable(summary(cars))
```

## plot


```{r my-plot, pressure}
plot(pressure)
```

## appendix
\appendix
my appendix
````

#### Approach 2

or you could use the `caption` package to add captions to your tables and plots

````
---
title: "Cross references between slides"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "default"
    keep_tex: true
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex    

---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Bullets with references

- Bullet 1: \ref{foo}
- Bullet 2: \ref{bar}
- Bullet 3: \hyperlinkappendixstart{appendix}


## table


```{r my-table, cars, echo = TRUE}
library(kableExtra)
kable(summary(cars))
```
\captionof{table}{foo}
\label{foo}

## plot


```{r my-plot, pressure}
plot(pressure)
```
\captionof{figure}{bar}
\label{bar}

## appendix
\appendix
my appendix
````

using this as `preamble.tex`:

```
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{caption}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the proposal. As far as I can see this simply jumps to the last page in the presentation. That is if the appendix contains several slides it would jump to the last slide of the appendix. (My presentation contains several "parts"; the appendix contains slides for each part which I would like to separate if feasible. Ideally, a general cross-reference would jump to the beginning of the appendix; as well as specific ones to specific parts/figs/tables of the appendix)

Comment: @mavericks it jumps to the first slide of the appendix, or more preciously to were `\appendix` is located in the code,  (the document will have to be compiled at least two times)

Comment: thank you very much for your very helpful and elaborate answer, which is greatly appreciated!

Comment: An advantage of the second approach is that, while slide titles might change during the preparation of a presentation, labels for figures and tables are likely stable over time

Comment: @MacUsers: Links might not necessarily work in presentation mode => Open presentation in Adobe Acrobat for Links to work properly in presentation mode

Comment: @mavericks I would recommend adobe anyway, as the native mac viewer does not support automatic slide transitions etc.

Comment: true! Would you have any recommendations on how to display notes during the LaTeX Beamer presentation? E.g., by displaying the notes on a separate screen?

Comment: @mavericks For a two-screen setup, I'm rather fond of this pdf viewer: http://iihm.imag.fr/blanch/software/osx-presentation/

Comment: this looks like a very interesting tool! Thank you so much for the hint!